Best *deterministic* scheme (no SSSS) to turn a secret into 6 shards—with any 2 of these rebuilding the secret
What's the best deterministic scheme (i.e. no Shamir Secret Sharing Scheme) to turn a secret into 6 shards—with any 2 of these shards rebuilding the secret?

What kind of security do you expect to get from a deterministic secret sharing scheme?

And, any question that asks for the 'best' of something, without any more details, is underspecified.  There are a lot of ways something could be the 'best' (is it the simplest; is it the fastest (on a specific platform); does it use the least amount of resources, is it the easiest to implement correctly)

@poncho You are right. My mistake. By specifying “best”, I meant simple to implement yet “doing the job”. And I guess I was hoping you might come up with a XOR scheme of some sort…

A deterministic secret sharing scheme with more than one share/shard can't be information-theoretically secure, and is bound to be insecure for low-entropy shared secret. Argument: it will be possible to eliminate some if not most key values, by running the algorithm on a tentative secret value, and testing if the shares that it outputs match what's known of the shares. If not, the secret being tested is eliminated. If that did not disclose information about the secret, then the shares would be independent of the secret, making it impossible to reconstruct the secret.
Within that limitation, we can do the following:

Perform key stretching on the secret to share by feeding it to a purposely slow memory-hard function such as Argon2 (sometime called a Password-Based Key Derivation Function, but please do not confuse with the obsolete and much less secure PBKDF2 or it's ancestors). We should set the workfactor parameters to the highest we can afford, and the output size to the amount of random material needed in the next step.
Use any secret sharing scheme with information-theoretic security, like Shamir Secret Sharing, except that instead of randomness we use the deterministic output of the previous step.

I do not claim that's optimal in the sense of disclosing as little as possible about the secret, or making the shares as small as possible.
